# window batch) manipulating 'for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`find "str" path`)' sentence

Tags: command-line, bash, batch, cmd.exe

I symplified the problem here:

```
@echo off
set res=

echo 'na':
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`find "na" things.txt`) do set res=%%f

echo %res%

pause>nul
```

and that things.txt file in the code is like:

```
banana
apple
napoleaon
nellson
naples
paris
```

As you expect, the result is just

```
naples
```

because 'naples' contains 'na' and is located below in the text than other words contain 'na.' But what I want is printing other words like 'banana' and 'napoleaon' above the 'naples.'

Specifically, I want to put them into the variable `res` through the for /f "usebackq" %%f in ('find "str" path') command.

How can I do that?...

Comment: put the echo inside the loop

Comment: `for /f "usebackq" %%f in ('find "na" things.txt') do echo %%f ` will print                                                                                                                      `banana napoleaon naples`                                                                                                                       but what I want is manipulating the command to put each of the word into variable seperately

Comment: concatenate `set res=%res% %%f`

Comment: What do you mean..? That doesn't work..:(

Comment: right. so then please add in header `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` and then concatenate with `set res=!res! %%f` i truly hate windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349189

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: Thank you! now it works, though it work quite differently from what I wanted.

Comment: you really saved me from despair.. now I can continue finishing my work