# options for [for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`find "" path`) do] sentence in batch

Tags: command-line, bash, batch, cmd.exe

I symplified my problem:

```
@echo off
set res=

for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`find "a" list.txt`) do set res=%%f
echo %res%

pause>nul
and that things.txt file in the code is like:
```

list.txt file in the code is:

```
apple
pitch
pear
melon
mango
```

As you expect, the result of this code is

```
mango
```

because the line 'mango' is located below the line 'apple' and 'pear'

But the result I want is

```
apple
```

or

```
pear
```

Specifically, I want to put each of the other values above `mango` such as `apple` and `pear` into the variable `res` using option keys provided.

is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1576152

Answer (score 2):

Here, only the last match is selected because `res` is overwritten each time. This will save all the matches delimiting them with space:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "fruits=" 
for /f ^tokens^=^* %%a in ('type list.txt ^| find "a"') do set "fruits=!fruits! %%a"
set "fruits=!fruits:~1!
```

Now `echo !fruits!` will give `apple pear mango`.

If you want to get first two matches use this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ("!fruits!") do echo %%a %%b
```

will give `apple pear` and to save it in fruits use `do set "fruits=%%a %%b"`. You can modify `tokens` to select the words delimited by space.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Echo off

<con: CD /d "%~dp0" && Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in (list.txt)do echo\%%i|find "a" >nul && (
   set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call set "_res_!_cnt!=%%~i" )

for /l %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do echo\_res_%%L==!_res_%%L!
endlocal
```

- Output:

```
_res_1==apple
_res_2==pear
_res_3==mango
```

You can use a `for /f` loop and an `echo\"a"|find "a"` if "a",  is found, the operator `&&` will continue, and a counter will be used to define a `variable_counter_actual=current_occurrence`, so that you can make use of any occurs between 1st and last.

For usage example, you have the output of the `for /l` loop, which will list all occurrences starting at 1, following from 1 in 1 to the total (!_cnt!), each `!_res_%%L!`.

- For only the first two occurrences:

```
for /l %%L in (1 1 2)do echo\_res_%%L==!_res_%%L!
```

- Use only the occurrences you want, for example 1st and 3rd:

```
for %%L in (1,3)do echo\_res_%%L==!_res_%%L!
```

- Or, simply use:

```
echo\!_res_1!
echo\!_res_2!
```